# Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2019 automatically share the Android SDK?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I previously developed Android with Visual Studio 2019, which was recently released in Visual Studio 2022, and I want to install it, but disk space is not enough! If Xamarin is also installed in Visual Studio 2022, can I use the Android SDK under the previous Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Yes, the Android SDK should be installed in a common path that is independent of the VS version you are using

Comment: But I can't set the path to the Android SDK in the setup of Visual Studio 2022, do I automatically use the Android SDK path from visual Studio 2019?

Comment: just use the default.  They should be the same for both versions

Comment: Hi, Jason, Do you mean that Visual Studio 2022 automatically uses the Android SDK for Visual Studio 2019 by default?

Comment: by default, there is only one install of the Android SDK, and both versions of VS should refer ot it.

Comment: Hi, Jason, You're right, I installed Visual Studio 2022 in the afternoon, no problem, Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 used the same Android SDK! Thank you very much!